# How to check if many-to-many-to-many... exist in table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have 4 tables, and the 4 are foreign keys in one junction table.

The problem is that I need to retrieve the jnction values that are missing.

For example:

```
Table A       Table B      Table C     Table D             
--------     ---------    ---------   ----------
  1              4            7          A
  2              5            8          B



 JUNCTION TABLE
-----------------
  1   4   7   A
  1   4   7   B
  1   4   8   A
  1   4   8   B
  1   5   7   A
  1   5   7   B
  1   5   8   A
  1   5   8   B      
  2   4   7   A
  2   4   7   B
  2   4   8   A
  2   4   8   B
  2   5   7   A
  2   5   7   B
  2   5   8   A
  2   5   8   B
```

So if the column 1 5 8 B is missing, when I run the query it shows 1 5 8 B..

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a cross join on your source tables, then join the result of that to your junction table.

EDIT: Kudos to andy holaday for pointing out that MySQL does not have FULL OUTER JOIN.

```
select x.*
from (select *
      from a,b,c,d) as x
left outer join j
    on (x.a = j.a and
        x.b = j.b and
        x.c = j.c and
        x.d = j.d)
where j.a is NULL and
      j.b is NULL and
      j.c is NULL and
      j.d is NULL
```

Comment: Right idea but [MySQL doesn't support FULL OUTER JOIN](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3362079/1248931) so you will need to make this a `RIGHT JOIN` and test all the `j` columns for `NULL`. Also you have a typo: `j.d = j.d)`

Comment: Good point, thanks!  Half T-SQL going on here.  It has been edited.  And the typo...well...I will blame that on me answering via mobile!

Answer (score 0):

Use this query, which does an outer join to junction from the 4 tables cross joined:

```
select a.col, b.col, b.col, d.col
from tablea a
cross join tableb b
cross join tablec c
cross join tabled d
left join junction j 
    on j.cola = a.col
    and j.colb = b.col
    and j.colc = c.col
    and j.cold = d.col
where junction.cola is null; -- sufficient to test just one
```